# Sms Retrieving not working?

Tags: android

I am using 2.1 platform.Trying to retrieve all the SMS from the Emulator. No **Compile error**,  **NO Logcat Error** in my code.I included the permission for ReadSMS in manifest file.When I run the code no display in the ListView. In my XML file there is only one ListView. On that ListView I am trying to display all the SMS of format ( Number : Sms Body) from the Emulator.

**Code**

```
public class SMSActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListView lview;
    String Body  = "" ; 
    int Number;
    ArrayList<String> smslist=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lview =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,smslist);
    lview.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), new String[] { "_id", "address", "date", "body","read" },"_id = "+null, null, null);

    while(c.moveToNext()){

    Number = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));

   Body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();

   smslist.add( Number + "\n" + Body);
    }
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    c.close();
}
}
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: see this.. : http://android10.org/index.php/articlesfullapplications/241-sms-messaging-in-android-send-and-receive and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11356430/1168654 it may help you.

Comment: This site is only about Sending and Retrieving SMS in between Emulators.....check my code ...please

Comment: hey you forgotten about second link i past it here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11356430/1168654

Comment: Oh Sorry,It is very informative about the things I need.Thanks for sending this link.. One happy news I got the Solution by changing the Cursor query. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are doing is you just mentioning that you want to read sms but you forgot to say
from which folder you need them.e.g from inbox,outbox etc..

If you need to read SMS from inbox use following.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
```

You can also query column names using

```
for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {

    Log.i("info", cursor.getColumnName(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vipul...I changed only the cursor it is working  properly, I need to know about the for loops below ..what purpose we use it here Actually ?